# Receiving changes from server in real-time, Server/Ajax-Push, HTML5 Websockets, ready-made server implementations or what?

Tags: php, ajax, html, comet, server-push

I’ve been working on a php project where I’m trying to create a cards game.

That obviously needs to be updated in real-time, so, having almost finished the underlying server logic, I went for the naiive/obvious solution for fetching the data from the server - heartbeats or periodic ajax requests - and was thrilled to see the page working through that.

Misery began when I started thinking there could be a less "stressful" way, that’s when I found a couple of conversations here (and in other websites) about "Comet" and “AJAX PUSH” or “Server Push” which I’ve read about intensively.

I found a [demo](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) in zeitoun.net which was very simple and ridiculously easy to make it work on my localhost.

As I was writing this question I've gone through the "similar question" panel. and to be honest it's very confusing which option to go with.

Which would you recommend, knowing that I wanna make sure the website can serve up to 2000 users, and that I'm using PHP on Apache?

1. Keep using the current method, periodic client ajax requests (I've refined the server response to that, and it actually returns nothing most of the time unless a change was to be sent, but still I'm worried about the amount of hits per second the server is going to recieve).
2. Go for the "too good to be true" solution at [zeitoun.net](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start).
3. Use [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) which will require me to switch my operating system to Linux (which I'm willing to do if it turned out to be a promising solution).
4. Take a deeper look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets and go for HTML5 Websocket instead (regardless of browser-support and used fallbacks).
5. None of the above?

Comment: have you every considered `socket.io` & `node.js`  ???

Comment: I spent last night looking into it and followed a couple of introductory tutorials.  Although it counts as an independent language, it'd be great if it was a good and efficient solution for my problem.  I'll keep studying it and see where I get.